# Next JS NextAuth Session Extension Problem

Tags: session, next.js, next-auth

I have an issue with extending the session to allow database fields to be used when a user signs in. Currently, only name, email & image are recognisable because they come by default with Next Auth. I want to allow my session to recognise things like first_name etc. Any idea of where I'm going wrong?

Prisma User Model

```
model User {
  id            Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String?
  first_name    String
  middle_name   String?
  last_name     String?
  email         String    @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  hashedPassword String?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}
```

Route.ts

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import  CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "../../../../../prisma/client";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider ({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: {label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email"},
                password: {label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "Password"}
            },

            //@ts-ignore
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) return null;

                const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({where: {email:  credentials.email}})

                if (!user) return null;

                const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.hashedPassword!);

                return passwordsMatch ? user : null;
            },
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!
        })
    ],
    session: {
      strategy: 'jwt'
    },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export {handler as GET, handler as POST};
```

Page.tsx (Snippet)

```
<p>Welcome Back, {session.user!.first_name}</p>
```

It won't recognise first_name

I need first_name to be recognised.